# Which post/page an image is attached to

Tags: plugins, media, media-library

When I filter by `unattached` in the Media Library, it returns images that are used in posts and pages.

Are there ways to see which specific posts/pages an image is attached to?

Comment: Please add some code snippet which you have tried.

Comment: Are you looking for a code based answer, or are you asking if this is currently available in the Admin dashboard user interface?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a post is "attached" to its parent post. It's the same as when a page has a parent page, there is no difference internally.

Keep in mind though, that not all images on a post are attached to that post, and an image can appear in posts it's not attached to.

If you're in the user interface, you can use the uploaded to link in the detail view

Comment: Thanks. By user interface you mean from the end-user front-end? not from the admin panel? I would like to be able to see on which posts/pages an image appears on. I can't seem to find this info anywhere. For example, if I would like to delete an image and I want to ensure it is not attach to any posts or pages or appears on any posts and pages, where can I find this information? Or if I would like to update an image, and I want to check all posts/pages that this image is on are correctly updated, where can I find this information? Thanks.

Comment: Images can only be attached to a single post. There is no global site wide list of all the places an image appears. Remember, this is a programming/development/technical stack, all answers are written from a programming point of view. If you need help using the user interface or have questions about using WP Admin and what's available in that UI, then you should post on the .org support forums. Also remember that answers will answer your original question, it isn't a discussion forum, if you have new questions you need to start a new question.

Comment: I think I was trying to understand your answer when you mentioned about user interface. User interface is too loosely used these days. I don't think I have asked any new questions other than rephrasing what I have posted. But thank you for your time.

Comment: If your question is purely about being able to look in the `wp-admin` area for what you want then the question needs to be asking on the .org support forums. If so, the original question needs to be clarified to make that clear ( and closed as offtopic ), otherwise it needs adjusting to make it clear you're looking for a code based answer. Remember this site is not for end users, it is for programmers, so it will be assumed unless you mention it that you're asking how to do this with PHP/javascript code.